# Remove selected item from the inlineadmin interface

Tags: python, django, model

I don't know if this can be done in the django rendered admin interface what I want to do is remove item that has been selected from a foreign key field

eg

```
--mary
   --matter
   --mary-ann
   --may
   --mary jane
```

when I select "mary-jane" I want mary jane off the list so it won't be selected twice.
eg

```
 --mary
   --matter
   --mary-ann
   --may
```

How can this be achieved? the model is like this

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name)
```

## admin

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('name')
admin.site.register(Test,TestAdmin)
```

Comment: please add more details and provide your admin class for better understanding.

Comment: do you mean model admin? because this is how my model class is

Comment: yes your model admin class

Comment: I think your are concerned about the change page while editing so that the already chosen value does not appear again ? right ? since there is no point of duplication while adding the record.

Comment: yes that is what I was talking about